# How to fix issue with state not equal to current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling a function that uses state but the state that is being used in function is old state even though if you use the react debugger on chrome it displays new state.

```
const [somevalue,setsomevalue] = useState("newstate")

    function myfunction()
    {
       console.log(somevalue)
    }

myfunction()
```

output:

```
oldstate
```

I was thinking of using forceUpdate() but I am using classless component.

```
const CauseCodeChangeHandler = (e) => {
  
      setSelectedCauseCode(e.target.value);
  };

const serQtyChangeHandler = (e) =>
  {
    
    if (SelectedCauseCode == "CUS")
    {
       
     
    }
    else if (SelectedCauseCode == "OPS")
    {
    }
    else if (SelectedCauseCode == 'OOW')
    {
      
    }
  }
```

my component:

```
<ServiceSelectInput changeHandler={CauseCodeChangeHandler}/>
```

It is using old CauseCode not one that I just selected.

Comment: With the amount of code provided there is no possible way (without an overridden definition of useState or console.log ) that it prints out `oldstate`

Comment: No @Samathingamajig maybe the line `const [somevalue,setsomevalue] = useState("newstate")` was inside of a callback and the OP was trying to update the value that way?

Answer (score 2):

This is the *stale closure* problem and is something that [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) is designed to address:

```js
import {useCallback, useState} from 'react';

function Component () {
  const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState('newstate');

  // This will make sure that `myFunction` is recreated
  // every time that `someValue` changes
  const myFunction = useCallback(() => console.log(someValue), [someValue]);

  // ...rest of component
}
```

Comment: I tried to use that. It is not working. It is using the old state when the function is called

Comment: @JoeySmith Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it’s not possible to help you further. If you can provide one, then it would be possible for me to run the code in order to debug.